# Updating .css file when debugging nothing updates. ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I created an MVC 2 Project. When I am Changing the attributes of an id on the Site.css nothing changes on the view. For example I changed the color:White to Color : Red. Run the Application nothing happens.
I have already cleared the cache of my IE and also press F5 as I saw in another post but it didn't help. I know this is a very simple question but if someone can help me it would be great. Below is the code

```
#logindisplay
{
font-size:1.1em;
display:block;
text-align:left;
margin:10px;
color:Red;
}
```

master page

```
<div id="logindisplay">
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Log in","Login","Accountnew") %>
          <%--  <%: Html.ActionLink("Login","Create","User") %>--%>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens when you hit `CTRL F5` ? Can you inspect `Site.css` in the browser and see the changes > Does rebuilding the project helps ?

Comment: I already clear the cache and nothing updates when I click CTRL F5 or just F5.

Comment: It changes if I change the text-align : to right for example but it wont change the color

Comment: Is it the font color you are trying to set or the background color ?

Comment: I'm trying to change the Font color

Comment: Did you place it in the end of the `Site.css` file? you can inspect the element in the browser console and see where it gets its color from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you Site.css file is loaded after all the other css. Otherwise there is big chance that the property is overridden.
Moreover don't use red in your css property , better use an html color code such as :

```
#FF0000
```

Finally, don't forget to put the color on your link and not on the div

example :

```
#logindisplay a{
color : #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks For the answer. I don't have enough reputation to Voteup :(